# Swift class init throws compile-time error "expected declaration"

Tags: ios, swift, initialization

I'm surely missing something very simple here. I've created a custom class and want to provide an init method to set a property on the class - simple. But the init method is throwing a compile-time error: "Expected declaration". I don't see any differences with the latest version of the Swift programming guide. What's wrong here?

```
import UIKit

class MyClass: NSObject {

    var thumbnailView: UIView

    init​(thumbnailView​: UIView) { //ERROR: Expected declaration
        self.thumbnailView = thumbnailView
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked BBEdit to zap your gremlins and it gave me back this:

```
class MyClass: NSObject {

    var thumbnailView: UIView

    init•(thumbnailView•: UIView) { //ERROR: Expected declaration
        self.thumbnailView = thumbnailView
    }

}
```

Two gremlins!

Comment: wow. I didn't even know problems with weird non-printing characters actually came up in real life.

Comment: Wow indeed! Never ran into that problem before.

Comment: If you copy-paste from certain places, it's quite common